# Eclipse Ubuntu JRE System Library

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am quite new to Ubuntu and completely new into Java/Eclipse

As I try to start this kind of thing

```
public class Name {     
   public static void main(String[] args) {         
    System.out.println("Hallo " + args[0]  + "!");      
   } 
}
```

I get

```
  Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]' in project 'Name'
```

So, as proposed in similar posts, I try to add the library in the propereties of eclipse. Add library -> JRE System Library -> Alternate JRE

Then I try to input the path to my JRE which I found out is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` however here I fail : eclipse does not accept it as a legal path to JRE!

Some help would be super nice :)

Comment: That is the path the the java binary, not the JRE (or JDK). Just point to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: get the same response: `Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found.`