# i am not able to find jre in eclipse even if install jdk in OS

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, java-11

i am new to eclipse wants to set up jdk (jre) in my project. i have installed jdk in my OS.

```
[![here is java version][1]][1]
```

[]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKqbh.png

[image: in eclipse not able to find JRE]

[image: see]
please can help me in this to resolve this . thanks in advance

Comment: You have to tell Eclipse about the JRE in 'Java > Installed JREs'. The Execution Environments will be filled in when you have done that.

Comment: in Execution Environments checked says No JREs in workspace compatible with specified execution environment: JavaSE-11

Comment: What do you have in 'Java > Installed JREs'? You must tell Eclipse about the JRE there

Comment: i have installed jdk in ubuntu not able to find the location to keep in installed JRES. for windows default location is  Windows C: > Program Files > Java, but ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your installed JDK to the Eclipse by following steps:

1. Right click your project > properties
2. Select “Java Build Path” on left, then “JRE System Library”, click Edit…
3. Select "Workspace Default JRE"
4. Click "Installed JREs"
5. If you see JRE you want in the list select it (selecting a JDK is OK too)
6. If not, click Search…, navigate to Computer > Windows C: > Program Files > Java, then click OK
7. Now you should see all installed JREs, select the one you want
8. Click OK/Finish

Comment: i am using ubuntu  not windows

Comment: could you please tell me in ubuntu which location i have give ?

Comment: This might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648855/eclipse-ubuntu-jre-system-library

Comment: @user15439867 Just select `/usr/lib/jvm` or the whole `/usr` directory in the Eclipse dialog for searching the Java Runtime.